# Is it possible to run Points2one in batch mode?

Tags: qgis, batch

Is it possible to run Points2one in batch mode (using Qgis 2.8.1 on Unbuntu 12.04)?

Basically I have 85 separate point layers and I want to create polygons using Points2one for each layer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is currently not possible to run Points2one in batch mode (without writing code).

There is a tool called **points to path** in the Processing toolbox which would cover the points to line use case and could be used in the Processing batch tool but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a tool for points to polygons yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer underdark its what I thought but I was hoping someone had come across this before. I have another related question which I will post separately which might be a better approach for my problem. cheers